# I can't define XMLParser in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I can't define simple XMLParser in Swift 3.

They always put ( coder : "Url_path" ) on auto correction.

I look at https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/xmlparser/1415575-init

```
let feedUrl = URL(string: "http://TEST/TEST.xml")!
let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: feedUrl)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because you have named your own class "XMLParser", so it conflicts with the existing XMLParser that you're trying to instantiate.

The solution is to rename your class to something else than "XMLParser". You will then be able to use `XMLParser(contentsOf: feedUrl)` because it will use the right class, not yours.